# Do we have a phrase expressing that you missed doing something but you decided to move ahead without getting back?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You packed your stuff for a trip to a place.

When you are half way to the place, you realized you forgot to take your ipad with you.

But you decided to keep on the trip rather than returning back home for the iPad.

Is it correct to say "**I missed the ipad, but don't worry about it, get on with the trip**"?

**Do we have a phrase expressing that you missed doing something but you decided to move ahead without getting back?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One phrase that springs to mind is **press on regardless**.

> I left my iPad behind, but don't worry, I'll just press on regardless.

More generally

> I've done / not done something, or something unexpected has happened
> but I'm going to ignore it and press on regardless.

Further thoughts
Another possibility in the case of the missing iPad is ...I'll just **do without it.**
**Press on regardless** can also be **carry on regardless**.